# How to update the assemblies and file using setup project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project

I've created a windows application in C#. The application has check for update feature. Whenever an update to the application is available, it downloads the setup file.

When we run the new setup it is successfully installed and we can see the new version in control panel. But the problem is that the assembly files and other files in installation directory are not updated. They are still the previous version of files.

I have set the following properties of the installer project:

**- DetectNewInstalledVersion : true**

**- RemovePreviousVersion: true**

Am I missing any property of setup project or is there any other approach to do that. I don't want to use any third party tool for setup creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must increment the file versions of those files that need replacing. That's because of the Windows Installer file replacement rules.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367835(v=vs.85).aspx